# Laravel 8 : cant change laravel auth redirection

Tags: php, laravel

I have installed adminlte https://github.com/jeroennoten/Laravel-AdminLTE/wiki , and previously set the default url after logging into '/ beranda'. But when I try to get it back to the original url which is '/ home', it doesn't work. Url remains pointing to 'beranda'. how to change it?

I've tried this:

```
composer dump-autoload
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:cache
php artisan route:cache
```

**config/adminlte.php**

```
'use_route_url' => false,

'dashboard_url' => 'home',

'logout_url' => 'logout',

'login_url' => 'login',

'register_url' => 'register',

'password_reset_url' => 'password/reset',

'password_email_url' => 'password/email',

'profile_url' => false,
```

**Auth/LoginController.php**

```
use AuthenticatesUsers;

/**
 * Where to redirect users after login.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME;

/**
 * Create a new controller instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
}
```

**Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php**

```
public const HOME = '/home';
```

**Providers/AuthServiceProvider.php**

```
public function boot()
{
    $this->registerPolicies();

    Gate::define('isAdmin', function ($user) {
        return $user->role == 'admin';
    });
    Gate::define('isMember', function ($user) {
        return $user->role == 'member';
    });
}
```

**Routes**

```
Auth::routes();
Route::get('/', [HomeController::class, 'index']);
Route::get('/beranda', [BerandaController::class, 'index'])
    ->middleware('can:isMember')
    ->name('beranda');
Route::get('/booking', [BookingController::class, 'index'])
    ->middleware('can:isMember')
    ->name('booking');
Route::get('/invoice', [InvoiceController::class, 'index'])
    ->middleware('can:isMember')
    ->name('invoice');
Route::get('/trip', [TripController::class, 'index'])
    ->middleware('can:isMember')
    ->name('trip');
Route::get('/setting', [SettingController::class, 'index']);
Route::get('/home', function () {
    return view('home');
})->name('home')->middleware('auth');
Route::get('/admin/beranda', [AdminBerandaController::class, 'index'])
    ->middleware('can:isAdmin')
    ->name('adminBeranda');
```

Comment: try to change protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME; to >>> protected $redirectTo = /home;     at Auth/LoginController.php

Comment: still not working . keep pointing to /beranda

Comment: Perhaps try running `php artisan cache:clear`?

Comment: Also, probably not causal but many of your routes seem to use `->name('member')`, I dont believe that's valid, the names should be unique for each route.

Comment: @WesleySmith thank you for correcting, i have improve my question. but still not working. always pointing to /beranda. I want to reinstall it, but i need to find best solution without reinstall auth and adminlte

Comment: Did you try clearing the cache?

Comment: yes i have, i also tried php artisan config:cache and php artisan route:cache

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry this is my mistake, on navbar menu login, i put link '/beranda' instead of 'login'

so when i click the link, beranda will check for login, event admin's role will redirect to beranda after login.